# how to fetch data using axios inside map method?

Tags: javascript, react-native, array.prototype.map

```
const devices = [1001, 1002, 1003];
const fetchData = () => {
     const fP = devices?.map(async (id) => {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`https://www.roads.com/road/ap/roadControl/${id}`, myHeaders);          
        return data.data;
    })

    return (fP);
};


const {data} = useQuery ("post", fetchData);
console.log(data);
```

In this following codes, I'm tring to fetch data from 3 API's using .map() method to change id's end of the API.

but using axios inside map method, i can't fetch the data from the API. if i don,t use .map() method, i can fetch the data without any issues.

something Like that:

```
const { data } = await axios.get(`https://www.roads.com/road/ap/roadControl/1001`, myHeaders);
```

If i use .map() method and inside use axois i can't fetch the data. i get undefined.

so how can i fix this issues, any can help me to fix it.

what should i do to fix it?

ThankYou for your trying in advance!.

**for my security reason i'm using here false api so you can use to work something valid api.**

Comment: Just change the `return` to `Promise.all(fP)`

Comment: still it undefined for the reload files.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what that means

Comment: If the `devices` array is required by the query, you should be providing it as part of the [query key](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/query-keys#if-your-query-function-depends-on-a-variable-include-it-in-your-query-key)

Comment: actually when i reload emulator it's given me undefined but if i save the files after reload emulator, everything is working fine so first lunch app is giving me an error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest you to try `Promise.all()` while fetching multiple API data at the same time.

```
const fetchData = async() => {
  const devices = [1001, 1002, 1003];

  const requestArray = await Promise.all(devices?.map((id) => {
     return axios.get(`https://www.roads.com/road/ap/roadControl/${id}`, myHeaders);
  }))

  console.log( JSON.stringify(requestArray) );
}
```

Since I do not have the header information, I cannot reproduce an example which is confirmed working. You can extract your data in `requestArray` instead of working in the `map()`.

Comment: i am getting first await error. so, where should i use the async if you help me.

Comment: Your `fetchData` function should be set as `async` too. Updated the answer.

Comment: still undefined Sir.

Comment: [TypeError: Array.from requires an array-like object - not null or undefined]

Comment: how to solve this error?

Comment: May be async process in map function creates error of that. Instead of returning `data.data`, I modified the code and you may extract data after fetch is finished.

Comment: when i reload the file it's given undefined